# simple neural network producing too high a loss value

Tags: python-3.x

I am just starting out with using Keras and want to build a super simple neural network. Using an arange array as x and y = x*2, I'm trying to train my model to predict based on this multiplication. While my model seems to run and produce results, the loss that I'm getting is way too high and the results is terrible given the simplicity of the model. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
x = np.arange(1,100).reshape((99,1))

y = x*2

x_test = np.arange(1,10).reshape((9,1))

y_test = x_test*2



keras.backend.clear_session()

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(4,input_dim = 1, activation = 'linear'))

model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'linear'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

model.fit(x, y,
          epochs=3,
          batch_size=32)

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

model.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Have you tried to train the model with more than 3 epochs (like a few tens/hundreds)? The loss is always pretty high for the first epochs.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code is correct, it just has not gone through enough epochs to converge, you can see that your model starts improving around 50th epoch,
[image: Loss Improvement]

Here you can see that around 200 Epochs the loss has improved Significantly.
[image: Loss around 250 epochs]

Take aways from this

1. Your model needs to run for a while before it starts to converge.
2. So Does this mean high number of epochs are always better? No, as high epochs can start over-fitting your model to the training data.

What you want to do is plot a graph between training and test/Validation accuracy and find out the point where it fits best, If you have any more queries, feel free to comment.